# Sort by values (descending) and then keys (ascending) in Python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following dictionaries:

```
mydict1 = {1: 11, 2: 4, 5: 1, 6: 1}
mydict2 = {1: 1, 5: 1}
```

For each one of them I'd like to first sort by values (descending) and then keys (ascendingly), yielding this output:

```
out_dict1 = [((1, 11), (2, 4), (5, 1), (6, 1)]
out_dict2 = [(1, 1), (5, 1)]
```

What's the way to do it?

I used this but cannot get the result consistently for two cases above:

```
sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
```

Comment: Are all keys and values always guaranteed to be numbers?  If so, then @thefoureye's solution is simplest.  If not, you need a little extra... which Python does enable thanks to its sort being guaranteed **stable**...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you want to sort the values in descending order, just negate the value of values in the function passed to the `key` parameter, like this

```
sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

Now, the values will be sorted in the descending order and if two values are equal, the keys will be considered and they will be sorted in the ascending order.

Comment: Just what I have been trying to look for days. And today I found out about lambda OMG they are so cool.